# Delete records that are almost repeated by seconds difference

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a problem in a SQL table, it is connected to an app that allows the user to scan books by their ISBN, there was a problem and for some reason the function that executes when an user scans a book is getting called multiple times, but for now I'm trying to delete the duplicated rows in the table. I have already deleted the rows that were inserted at the same instant (ex. 4 rows at '2024-03-21 02:35:11.000') but I noticed I have rows that are almost repeated but with only **1 or 2 seconds** difference, for example:

```
ID    | Date
30370 | 2024-03-21 02:35:11.000
30371 | 2024-03-21 02:35:12.000
30372 | 2024-03-21 02:35:14.000
30373 | 2024-03-21 02:35:15.000
```

How should I delete the *almost* duplicated rows and leave only one? Here's the query I used to delete the duplicated ones:

```
DELETE FROM <table>
WHERE Id NOT IN (
    SELECT MIN(ID)
    FROM <table>
    GROUP BY Date
)
```

Comment: Do a date compare.... or strip the millisecond or seconds off the date before grouping).

Comment: What @DaleK said, then just keep the first or last one perhaps.  Be cautious of one in the last ms of a minute/second and the next one right after in the NEXT minute/second.

Comment: that are seconds and not milliseconds,

Comment: Presumably the duplicated rows have duplicated data, like the same ISBN? And what nbk said, those rows are separated by seconds.

Comment: Yes the rows are completely duplicated, I did not notice those were seconds sorry

Comment: Do you want the first, last or any one row in the group to survive?

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM
  your_table
WHERE
  EXISTS (
    SELECT *
      FROM your_table AS lookup
     WHERE lookup.date   >= DATEADD(second, -1, your_table.date)
       AND lookup.date   <  your_table.date
       AND lookup.someid  = your_table.someid
  )
```